# How do I get java to recognize import com.wolfram.jlink

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a java program that uses mathematica code for processing and graphs while using java for the front end. From what I've been able to glean from the j/link tutorials on the wolfram site I will need to import com.wolfram.jlink in my java program like so:

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;
```

I can't seem to get it to work. When I try to compile my compiler says that the com.wolfram package does not exist. I'm guessing that I need to download and install the com.wolfram package somewhere but I don't know where to acquire it and google has been less than helpful.

In case it's helpful I'm running JRE 1.6 on a machine running windows 7.

Comment: Can we assume you have Mathematica installed? I ask this because you refer to online documentation, whereas, with MMA installed, you'd probably use internal documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the jars are on your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to solve the problem by including the JLink.jar file in my project.